# Modified Java Beans setter to return the Bean Class conflicts with Bean-Framework

Tags: java, javabeans

To support Fluent Programming Style i recently modified our Java Beans setter methods to return the Bean Class.
But now the Java Beans Activation Framework (rel 1.1) does no longer find the setters, as they don't return void.
Simply adding a new setter with return type void is not allowed, as methods must not only differ in return type.
Is there a work-around?

Comment: wrap the bean in a beanfacade and add the fluent stile to the latter. there's a refactor to create a facade in some IDE, which implements all methods with a delegate, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357784/can-eclipse-auto-generate-an-interface-of-a-3rd-party-library-class

Comment: Note that the JavaBeans definition specifies that setter methods should return `void`.  Changing the signature of a JavaBean may render it incompatible with some frameworks or libraries that are based on this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I address this issue using three types of methods: Getters, Setters, and *With*ers. The Withers support fluent programming, and I provide getters and setters to satisfy the Bean assumptions. For example:

```
public class MyBean {

    private int value;

    public int getValue(){ return this.value; }

    public void setValue(int v){ this.value = v; }

    public MyBean withValue(int v){ setValue(v); return this; }

}
```

Comment: I like this idea.  I would like a construction you could call on any class without modifying the class though.  Something with the ternary operator perhaps?

Comment: I think you meant to return `this`, i.e. the instance of MyBean

Comment: @Stroboskop Indeed. Fixed! :)